# Sonar plugin display java information in my own page

Tags: java, ruby, plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm developping a sonar plugin who retrieve information from the database in Java. I want to display these information
in my own page. I saw in Sonar 4.2 that I can create my own web Service in java. So it's perfect because I create
my own RubyRailsPage and I retrieve the information with my webService (who query the database) that I call from my ruby page using Ajax.

My Question is how can I do the same thing Sonar 4.1. Because I can't create my own webService in Java in Sonar 4.1.

**So I don't know how to retrieve information in java and display them in a rubyRailsPage ?**

I read somewhere that JavaFacade permit to use java objects in ruby page but it don't work and I don't know if it's the solution.

I hope my explication was clear.

Comment: Version 4.1 is nearly two and a half years old. The current L.T.S. version is 4.5.7, and the next L.T.S. version, 5.6, should be released in early June. Are you really sure you want to do development for 4.1?

Comment: Yes for the moment in my enterprise, sonar is in 4.1, so I have to find a solution for this version